# Verifying individual servers in a load balancing configuration

Tags: load-balancing

Here is my situation.  Recently, my production environment has been burned by a few Windows updates that caused some production servers to stop responding.  While we have since resolved the issue of both of the servers (which are in a load balancing configuration) getting updates on the same day, the question arouse, how do we check that the application running on each server is still working?  If we call the load balancing IP, we may or may not hit a server that is working.  So if the update takes out the application on one server, how do we know that this has happened

The only idea I have for this is to purchase 2 more SSL certificates and allocate 2 ip addresses and assign one to each server.  This way I would be guaranteed that I would know each server is up (we have a 3rd party service pinging our servers).  But I have to believe that there is a better way to do this?

Please note that I am a .Net developer by trade with only an extremely small smattering of networking and IIS experience, but I'm what my small company has.  So please assume I don't know where a lot of stuff is and dumb down the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Load balancer maintains live status of the servers ( based on timeouts or http health checks ). It uses this status to route the traffic only to active servers.

Generally, LBs have a dashboard through which you can check this status. If not, you can check it's logs.